# LoadLibrary Error 126 dependent on user rights

Tags: c++, winapi, loadlibrary

I have a strange issue, where my application that runs at my place doesn't work somewhere at customers place.
In my application I try to load another dll with `LoadLibrary()` from within the same folder.
If the application is run as normal user a `126 error` is returned. If the same application is started with Admin rights the dll is loaded correctly.

It's hard to diagnose because I cannot reproduce the error at my machine.
Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

OK, it was a dependency: the dll was a Debug-Build and the `MSVCP120D.dll` and `MSVCR120D.dll` could not be found. I could tell this by a Process Monitor-Log.

**BUT**: I have a log as normal user and a log as Admin and in both cases the dependencies cannot be found. Why does `LoadLibrary` work in case of Admin-rights??

Comment: Was the application installed in the `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` folder on the customers machine?

Comment: need more info - `LoadLibrary` used only dll name or full path ? what is the folder path ?

Comment: @KompjoeFriek was installed in `Program Files (x86)`

Comment: @RbMm: I just use the name of the dll without a path specified

Comment: Probably the OP has configured the CWDIllegalInDllSearch option, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2264107

Comment: Note that (if I remember rightly) this setting can prevent DLLs from being loaded from the current directory even if the current directory is also the application directory - it doesn't just remove it from the search path.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: good hint, but that wasn't the reason here. See my edit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`, which is pretty self-explanatory. Either the DLL you are loading, or one of its dependencies, cannot be found. Perhaps you failed to install the necessary dependencies, e.g. the MSVC runtime. Or perhaps it is something else.

You'll need to do some debugging and investigation. I would start by profiling the DLL load using Dependency Walker.

Comment: Dependency Walker hasn't been updated in ages. If you want to play it safe, using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) instead of Dependency Walker's profiling might be a better option.

Comment: Maybe. But then again dynamic linking has been basically stable for a long time. I'd expect DW to tell you which module could not be found.

Comment: The dll is there! The dependencies are in Windows/System folder and can be found. The question is: why can there be a difference between running as Admin and Non-Admin?!

Comment: Why don't you do what I suggest. Get some real information. Then nobody has to guess. Find out which dll cannot be found.

Comment: @joerg - "The dll is there!" - your dll by self not found or one of it dependencies ? try `LoadLibraryEx(pat,0, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES)` - if dll by self not found this call also fail, if problem in  depended dll - will be no errors here. and try full path use,in place dll name. will be same result ?

Comment: OK, so it was as I said. You now that you must not distribute the debug runtime?